# problem when upload file in play framework

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework, image-upload

I tried uploading a file, and placed the file in the "public / images" directory and it worked, but the file I uploaded was zero in size and certainly couldn't be opened

```
    public Result upload() throws IOException {
    Http.MultipartFormData<File> requestBody = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> profile_pic = requestBody.getFile("profile_pic");
    String dirPath = "public/images/";      

    if(profile_pic != null) {
        String name = profile_pic.getFilename();
        File file = profile_pic.getFile();
        System.out.println(file);


    File theDir = new File(dirPath);
    if (!theDir.exists()) {
        boolean result = false;

        try {
            theDir.mkdirs();
            result = true;
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            // handle it
        }
        if (result) {
            System.out.println("DIR created");
        }
    }


    try {

    File filex = new File(dirPath + name.toLowerCase());
    filex.createNewFile();

    file.renameTo(filex);


    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return ok("File uploaded ");
    }else {
    return badRequest("Eroor");
    }
}
```

[this is my file after upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEz62.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think creating a new file and renaming your old file to that name may cause trouble. I would recommend using the `move` method, see docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move).

Does your `System.out.println(file);` print what looks like a normal png file?